# How to Refresh (Update) an HTML Page For New Data After the Submit Button is Pressed

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form that is split into three major components. The top portion is essentially a header for displaying a magazine name.  This information does not change.

The middle portion is a table developed through a MySQL query for displaying the story information as a table of contents after it is entered in the bottom portion, which is a data entry screen.

The bottom portion, is a data entry screen for entering the information concerning each story contained in the magazine issue.

After entering the data and pressing the submit button in the bottom portion, the middle portion should be updated through the MySQL query to reflect the newly entered story. That was not happening.

Note: The code previously associated with this question has been removed for purposes of clarity. The solution was associated with how the various forms were called. My thanks to Sulthan Allaudeen for providing potential solutions. Currently, I am not familiar with utilizing jquery-ajax. Eventually I will need to learn.

Comment: Why do you have a such a vast `echo`  Just close the php tag before the html and open after that. Also You need to refresh the data by jquery-ajax call after submit button

Comment: The use of echo is to see how the code is operating. Basically error tracing. Unfortunately for me, I am unfamiliar with  jquery-ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to refreshing the form to display the addition of new data was to re-call it through the following line: "*include("new_stories.inc.php");*". This line is imediately executed just after the MySQL insert code in the data entry section of the form.

The middle section of the form "*new_stories.inc.php*" (the table of contents) queries the MySQL data base to retrieve the story information related to the current magazine issue. Re-calling the form is equivalent to a re-query.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP wanted to know how do the jquery and ajax call

**Step 1 :**

Recognize the Input

Have a button  with a class `trigger`

```
$(".trigger").click(function() 
{
//your ajax call here
}
```

**Step 2 :**

Trigger your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "yourpage.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
//your action
}
});
```

**Step 3 :**

Inside your success function show the result

```
$("#YourResultDiv").html(data);
```

For that you should create a div named as `YourResultDiv`

**Note :**

Inside your `yourpage.php` You should just print the table and it will be displayed as the output

Comment: Thanks. Will take some time to digest.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brief example of displaying the results of submitting a form without leaving the current page. Form submission is done with the help of Ajax.
Each form has it's own button for submission, hence the loop over matching elements in onDocLoaded.

**1. blank.php** form is submitted to this script

```
<?php
echo "-------------------------------<br>";
echo " G E T - V A R S<br>";
echo "-------------------------------<br>";
var_dump( $_GET ); echo "<br>";

echo "-------------------------------<br>";
echo " P O S T - V A R S<br>";
echo "-------------------------------<br>";
var_dump( $_POST ); echo "<br>";
echo "<hr>";

if (count($_FILES) > 0)
{
    var_dump($_FILES);
    echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```

**2. blank.html** Contains 2 forms, shows the result of submitting either of them to the above script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementById(id);}
function allByClass(className,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByClassName(className);}
function allByTag(tagName,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByTagName(tagName);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}

function toggleClass(elem, className){elem.classList.toggle(className);}
function toggleClassById(targetElemId, className){byId(targetElemId).classList.toggle(className)}

function hasClass(elem, className){return elem.classList.contains(className);}
function addClass(elem, className){return elem.classList.add(className);}
function removeClass(elem, className){return elem.classList.remove(className);}

function forEachNode(nodeList, func){for (var i=0, n=nodeList.length; i<n; i++) func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList); }

// callback gets data via the .target.result field of the param passed to it.
function loadFileObject(fileObj, loadedCallback){var reader = new FileReader();reader.onload = loadedCallback;reader.readAsDataURL( fileObj );}

function myAjaxGet(url, successCallback, errorCallback)
{
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
            successCallback(this);
    }
    ajax.onerror = function()
    {
        console.log("AJAX request failed to: " + url);
        errorCallback(this);
    }
    ajax.open("GET", url, true);
    ajax.send();
}

function myAjaxPost(url, phpPostVarName, data, successCallback, errorCallback)
{
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
            successCallback(this);
    }
    ajax.onerror = function()
    {
        console.log("AJAX request failed to: " + url);
        errorCallback(this);
    }
    ajax.open("POST", url, true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send(phpPostVarName+"=" + encodeURI(data) );
}

function myAjaxPostForm(url, formElem, successCallback, errorCallback)
{
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
            successCallback(this);
    }
    ajax.onerror = function()
    {
        console.log("AJAX request failed to: " + url);
        errorCallback(this);
    }
    ajax.open("POST", url, true);
    var formData = new FormData(formElem);
    ajax.send( formData );
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);
function onDocLoaded()
{
    forEachNode( allByClass('goBtn'), function(elem){elem.addEventListener('click', onGoBtnClicked, false);} );
}

function onGoBtnClicked(evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();
    var thisElem = this;
    var thisForm = thisElem.parentNode;

    myAjaxPostForm('blank.php', thisForm, onPostSuccess, onPostFailed);

    function onPostSuccess(ajax)
    {
        byId('tgt').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    }
    function onPostFailed(ajax)
    {
        //byId('tgt').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        alert("POST FAILED!!!!");
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
<style>
#page
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.controls, .tabDiv
{
    margin: 8px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.tabDiv
{
    overflow-y: hidden;
    min-width: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.tabDiv > div
{
    padding: 8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='page'>

    <div class='tabDiv' id='tabDiv1'>
        <!-- <div style='padding: 8px'> -->
        <div>
            <form id='mForm' enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <label>Name: </label><input name='nameInput'/><br>
                <label>Age: </label><input type='number' name='ageInput'/><br>
                <input type='file' name='fileInput'/><br>
                <button class='goBtn'>GO</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='tabDiv' id='tabDiv2'>
        <!-- <div style='padding: 8px'> -->
        <div>
            <form id='mForm' enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <label>Email: </label><input type='email' name='emailInput'/><br>
                <label>Eye colour: </label><input name='eyeColourInput'/><br>
                <label>Read and agreed to conditions and terms: </label><input type='checkbox' name='termsAcceptedInput'/><br>
                <button class='goBtn'>GO</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--    <hr>    -->
    <div class='tabDiv'>
        <div id='tgt'></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Will take some time to digest.